# HttpUtility.ParseQueryString Mono 4.8 Xamarin Mac Upgrade Issue

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.mac

I have an app I have been working on that was running fine.

I upgraded to the latest Xamarin with mac support and now I get an error when I try to use HttpUtility.ParseQueryString.

I have an App.config file and it is telling me that it can't parse it, but this happens when trying to call ParseQueryString. How are those 2 related?

I thought I had found the problem because my app also has a ServiceReferences.ClientConfig file for http client settings. I copied my App.config  section to the ServiceReferences.ClientConfig file and that fixed it until I went to show my fellow dev the new error.

The new error was saying something about Path.Combine path1 being null.

I looked up that error and found a reference to a page talking about MacSupport in xamarin here: https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/8556026/

I don't know if they are related, but that is the closest I found to the stack trace I was seeing.

Can anyone tell me what changed in Mono 4.8 for Mac in Xamarin that would cause an issue with HttpUtility.ParseQueryString and how to solve it?

Comment: please post the relevant code and the specific errors/exceptions that you're getting

Comment: I am not sure what to post that would be helpful. What I ended up doing was just copying the HttpUtility methods that I actually needed an just using the source. I decided there just wasn't any way to get the whole Http system to initialize in my case as an end user app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System.Configuration is a common point of pain during mono upgrades, as it's behavior sometimes subtly (or not so subtly) changes.

You'll need to post a much larger chunk of information here for anyone to be able to help you.

Or you could post on the [XM Forms](https://forums.xamarin.com/categories/mac) or [file a bug](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/index.cgi) if you believe this is a bug, as those are a more appropriate place for such reports.

Comment: I am not sure what to post that would be helpful. What I ended up doing was just copying the HttpUtility methods that I actually needed an just using the source. I decided there just wasn't any way to get the whole Http system to initialize in my case as an end user app.

Comment: That may not be a terrible idea, if your use case is very small. System.Configuration issues can be really painful.